# When a question turned out to be a problem with "Typos" what do I do?

Tags: discussion

Let's say an **OP** didn't see the **typo** in my code and thought was a problem of the algorithm, logic, etc...

In that case,

what should the **OP** do to their post? Should the OP **delete** their post because a typo is a trivial error? And what should the **repliers** do when seeing that kind of questions? Should they just point it out on the **comment** or just post an **answer** with saying "Hey, you have a typo"?

Comment: You flag the question for closure. Such a question is not useful for future visitors. You can leave a comment to help the OP.